# Combobox dropdownlist is not filling from datagridview row

Tags: c#, winforms

I want when I click on *datagridview* row then my two text boxes and *combobox* fill with the corresponding values but two text boxes fill accurately but category dropdown is not filling.

My C# code is

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex !=-1)
    {
        //edit = 1;
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        proID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["proIDGV"].Value.ToString());
        proTxt.Text = row.Cells["nameGV"].Value.ToString();
        barcodetxt.Text = row.Cells["barcodeGV"].Value.ToString();
        catDD.SelectedValue = row.Cells["catIDGV"].Value.ToString();// not working properly due to which edit button is not working
       // catDD.SelectedItem = row.Cells["catGV"].Value.ToString();//Also Write this line of code but not produce the desire result
        MainClass.Disabled(leftPanel);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir i am working in windowForms

Comment: You need to show us how you set the DataSource of the ComboBox.

Comment: Are the items in the combobox filled correctly? Your code only shows selecting not filling.

Comment: Check values of comboBox its value should match with datagridview selected row category value

Comment: If the values in the combobx.Items are filled with the possible values from the DGV columns then `catDD.SelectedItem= row.Cells["catIDGV"].Value.ToString();` should work. If it doesn't the values or column name is/are incorrect.

Comment: You may want to bind the Items to a dgv columns like so: `var data = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                         .Select(x => x.Cells[0].Value).ToList();
            comboBox1.DataSource = data;`

Comment: Replace`[0]`  with `["catIDGV"]` in your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For category dropdown, which is a combo-box, to have a SelectedItem or SelectedValue you should already have all the possible categories in the "items" property, otherwise, the programming cannot select the category out of nowhere. To select items which don't exist you need to add an item first, or if you don't really need the items afterward you can just use:

```
catDD.Text = row.Cells["catIDGV"].Value.ToString();
```

Although I would not recommend doing it this way.

The other way is that you can add items by doing this (this is what I recommend):

**Edit: You first add the item then select it.**

```
string item = row.Cells["catIDGV"].Value.ToString(); // Your selected item in DataGridView
catDD.Items.Add(item); // Add the item
catDD.SelectedItem = item; // Select the item
```

Comment: Did you try adding the categories in the combo-box item by going to the items property?

Comment: Please select my answer as the official answer, if it works. Your welcome.

Comment: Sir I don't know how to select official answer  by I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: You have already selected it. Hey, you learned something :) Thanks!